# How to print jaxb to java object in to logger

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, logging, jaxb

Hi by following the below link i am able to convert JAXB to java object and print it in console using below statement.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

```
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
```

But i want to print the output in logger.

ex)log.info(customer) or log.debug(customer)

I am using Apache log4j.Does anyone have any idea??

Comment: Write it to a `StringWriter` and the log `stringWriter.toString()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below a possible way..

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
//set customer attributes 
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(customer, stringWriter );
log.info(stringWriter.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you.It works great.Is there any pretty print option in stringWriter because rightNow it prints in a single horizontal line.

Comment: You should add this line to format the output `marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);`